# To create a content rich page for an IT Product/Service or not?

Tags: seo, google

I’m unsure what will be the best for performance between these scenarios.

Make a page on website that is full of content describing a service/product we offer.

Or

Make a page on website that is brief content, then use blog posts to really describe what it is and link to it?

What would the best results be for visitors?

Comment: You tagged this as "SEO", but you ask what is best for visitors.   Are you asking which is a best user experience or are you asking which will get better rankings?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your objective is to rank your site for search, then the pages with the best content on them have the highest chances of success. Adding the product to this page instead of an external page increases their content value which should help in the site's rankings.

If you want to rank the product on its own, assuming there is enough search volume for the product and there isn't enough competition that would make it impossible to rank, then you might want to have your own product page separate from the blog post. In this scenario, the content above the fold is the product and so it may have a higher chance of ranking for searches on the product than a blog post might.

In the first scenario, you can have users scroll to the product with linked anchor divs. You can also put the product on your blog page and have a separate product page as well. You may choose to add rel canonical on the product page pointing back to the blog post if the content seems duplicated.

If your blog post is very long, then you would probably want to have a separate product page as well. Sites that have 3,000 word pages with the product at the bottom don't seem to rank as well as sites that have a blog and have separate product pages. Products on Amazon are product pages with descriptions of the products and aren't long blog posts. An Amazon style product page on your site is likely to perform well.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest a third scenario. Which would involve a content strategy that is more of a combination of the two, thus creating a page which nested under services, and provides enough detail for a consumer to fully understand the features and benefits of your product/service which you are selling.

Additionally, if this product/service is very important to your business, you may want to add some information about it on your homepage - which would be at your discretion.

Navigability and user experience will play a huge role in the success of any website. You would not want a user to have to try and go through different blog posts to find all of the information which is relevant and required to fully understand the underlying product or service. Rather, use the blog to establish the efficacy of the product/service - which can be done by posting case studies, scenarios which it could be used - so on and so forth.

Let me know if I can offer any further detail. Hope that this helps!